# Unreal Engine 4 + Qt Widget

Tags: c++, qt, unreal-engine4, game-development

Working on project with UE4. I want to create UI with using Qt Designer and all Qt UI tools. I have already done opening window with some Qt forms (treeview and group of checkboxes) but I failed transmit picture from Unreal Engine window to QWidget.

I read about HWDL window, but i didn't found any information about realization. Found only how to get HWDL from UE4, but didn't found how to set to QWidget or wise versa get HWDL from QWidget and set it for UE4 (I think the second one better).

Maybe someone have done it? Or know approach to do it.

Comment: Generally, UE4 supports it's own UI Designer : https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/UMG
But if you want to make your QT talk with UE4, maybe you could try find some example for "raw" C++ approach that could be able to talk to both UE4 libraries and QT libraries?

Comment: Thank's for your answer! I know about standard UI Designer, but I would like make UI like a simple Windows\Linux window UI. What Do you mean "raw" c++ approach? Without Blueprint?

Comment: By stating "raw" c++ I think about writing some C++ library for handling communication between QT and UE4 libraries. You could try to write some C++ code to set from QT code the image you want to place in UE4 and then in UE4 call something like GetImage from your custom C++ lib :-) some simple set/get functions :-) Don't know if this is the best solution, it's just some idea :-)

Comment: Not sure but perhaps this will be of use: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#winId